# String a Json C#

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

Hola amigos tengo un endpoint donde mi respuesta, es la siguiente.

```
"{\r\n  \"Table\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 100.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"EDIFICIO CENTRAL\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 101.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"XONACA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 102.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"HIDALGO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 103.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"INDEPENDENCIA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 104.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"ATLIXCO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 105.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"TEZIUTLAN\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 109.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"IZUCAR DE MATAMOROS\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 107.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"CHOLULA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 108.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"AMOZOC\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 110.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"TEHUACAN\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 111.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"SAN MARTIN\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 112.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"TECAMACHALCO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 113.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"AXOCHIAPAN\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 115.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"DORADA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 116.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"CUAUTLA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 117.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"CORDOBA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 118.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"TULANCINGO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 119.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"MARTINEZ DE LA TORRE\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 120.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"TEXCOCO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 121.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"XALAPA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 122.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"VERACRUZ\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 123.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"PACHUCA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 124.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"CUERNAVACA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 125.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"TULA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 126.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"HUAUCHINANGO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 127.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"HUAMANTLA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 128.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"TECAMAC\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 129.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"VALSEQUILLO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 130.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"ACATLAN\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 131.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"ZUMPANGO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 132.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"POZA RICA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 133.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"ZACAPOAXTLA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 134.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"MISANTLA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 135.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"LARA GRAJALES\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 136.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"PYME\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 137.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"AUTOMOTRIZ\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 138.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"AGROSUMATE\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 139.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"PEROTE\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 140.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"ZACATLAN\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 141.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"COATEPEC\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 142.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"CARDEL\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 143.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"ACATZINGO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 144.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"TLAPACOYAN\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 145.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"ACTOPAN\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 146.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"TLAXCALA\"\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}"
```

Lo que necesito es convertir esta respuesta en un json , para que de ese json pueda obtener un modelo y pueda pasarle la respuesta un `picker` de xamarin , alguien podría ayudarme?

Comment: Hola amigo, has tratado algo, te sugiero agregarlo a tu pregunta, cuando preguntes también te sugiero realizarlo por partes si el requerimiento es extenso, por ejemplo primero trata de obtener los datos de la respuesta, saludos.

Comment: No se si estoy escribiendo locuras (si es asi me lo hacen saber), pero pareciera que el proveedor de tu endpoint te retornara como respuesta un mime type de tipo `plain/text` y no un `application/json`. Creo que deberias de ponerte en contacto con el proveedor. Adicional podrias ser mas especifico en tu pregunta, como por ejemplo: el codigo con que realizas el request, como estas tratando de reeplazar los `\r\n` etc.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa tienes razón en todo lo que comentas, si va a recibir ese tipo de respuesta deberá de reemplazar algunos caracteres.

Answer (score 1):

Para convertir tu cadena a Json, puedes realizarlo de esta forma, a partir de tu respuesta debes eliminar los caracteres `"\r\n"` y "\"":

```
  String jsonStr = "{\r\n  \"Table\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 100.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"EDIFICIO CENTRAL\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 101.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"XONACA\"\r\n ...................";

  jsonStr = jsonStr.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace(@"\", "");
```

Ahora una opción es usar [Newtonsoft.Json NuGet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio) , aquí como instalarlo

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio

de esta forma podrías obtener el objeto Json a partir de la cadena:

```
  String jsonStr = "{\r\n  \"Table\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 100.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"EDIFICIO CENTRAL\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 101.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"XONACA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 102.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"HIDALGO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 103.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"INDEPENDENCIA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 104.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"ATLIXCO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 105.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"TEZIUTLAN\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 109.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"IZUCAR DE MATAMOROS\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 107.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"CHOLULA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 108.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"AMOZOC\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 110.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"TEHUACAN\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 111.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"SAN MARTIN\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 112.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"TECAMACHALCO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 113.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"AXOCHIAPAN\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 115.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"DORADA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 116.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"CUAUTLA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 117.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"CORDOBA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 118.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"TULANCINGO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 119.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"MARTINEZ DE LA TORRE\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 120.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"TEXCOCO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 121.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"XALAPA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 122.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"VERACRUZ\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 123.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"PACHUCA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 124.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"CUERNAVACA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 125.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"TULA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 126.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"HUAUCHINANGO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 127.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"HUAMANTLA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 128.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"TECAMAC\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 129.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"VALSEQUILLO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 130.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"ACATLAN\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 131.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"ZUMPANGO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 132.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"POZA RICA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 133.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"ZACAPOAXTLA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 134.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"MISANTLA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 135.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"LARA GRAJALES\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 136.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"PYME\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 137.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"AUTOMOTRIZ\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 138.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"AGROSUMATE\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 139.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"PEROTE\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 140.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"ZACATLAN\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 141.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"COATEPEC\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 142.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"CARDEL\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 143.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"ACATZINGO\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 144.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"TLAPACOYAN\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 145.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"ACTOPAN\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"CLAVE_S\": 146.0,\r\n      \"SUUCRSAL\": \"TLAXCALA\"\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}";

  jsonStr = jsonStr.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace(@"\", "");  

  dynamic sucursales = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStr);

  Console.WriteLine("sucursales : " + sucursales);
```