# problema json en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

quisiera que me puedan ayudar estoy realizando un json en sql server, he unido dos consultas pero al momento de salir me sale " y \ 
como acontinuación el resultado

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tablajson](
    [level] [int] NULL,
    [columnDef] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [header] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [isdata] [int] NULL,
    [type] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [mode] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [orden] [int] NULL,
    [orden2] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'NUM_10', N'Total semanal clientes nuevos', 11, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 10)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'DEN_10', N'Meta semanal clientes nuevos', 12, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 11)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'DIV_10', N'% Avance semanal', 13, N'percent', NULL, 4, 12)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'EXT_10', N'Total Acumulado en el Mes', 9, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 8)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'ACU_10', N'Meta acumulada del mes', 10, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 9)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_10', N'Total Acumulado en el Mes, mes anterior', 8, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 7)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'NUM_11', N'Total semanal prospectos', 5, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'DEN_11', N'Meta semanal prospectos', 6, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 5)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'DIV_11', N'% Avance semanal', 7, N'percent', NULL, 4, 6)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'EXT_11', N'Total Acumulado en el Mes', 3, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'ACU_11', N'Meta acumulada del mes', 4, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 3)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_11', N'Total Acumulado en el Mes, mes anterior', 2, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'NUM_18', N'Clientes desembolsados', 27, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 26)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'DEN_18', N'Total clientes', 28, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 27)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'DIV_18', N'% Efectividad', 29, N'percent', NULL, 4, 28)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_18', N'% Efectividad, mes anterior', 26, N'percent', NULL, 4, 25)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'NUM_19', N'Clientes desembolsados', 31, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 30)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'DEN_19', N'Total clientes', 32, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 31)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'DIV_19', N'% Efectividad', 33, N'percent', NULL, 4, 32)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_19', N'% Efectividad, mes anterior', 30, N'percent', NULL, 4, 29)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'NUM_500', N'Saldo recuperado', 35, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 34)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'DEN_500', N'Saldo total', 36, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 35)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'DIV_500', N'% Efectividad', 37, N'percent', NULL, 4, 36)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_500', N'% Efectividad, mes anterior', 34, N'percent', NULL, 4, 33)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'NUM_60', N'Saldo recuperado', 39, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 38)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'DEN_60', N'Saldo total', 40, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 39)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'DIV_60', N'% Efectividad', 41, N'percent', NULL, 4, 40)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_60', N'% Efectividad, mes anterior', 38, N'percent', NULL, 4, 37)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'NUM_7', N'Clientes desembolsados', 15, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 14)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'DEN_7', N'Total clientes', 16, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 15)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'DIV_7', N'% Efectividad', 17, N'percent', NULL, 4, 16)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_7', N'% Efectividad, mes anterior', 14, N'percent', NULL, 4, 13)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'NUM_8', N'Clientes desembolsados', 19, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 18)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'DEN_8', N'Total clientes', 20, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 19)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'DIV_8', N'% Efectividad', 21, N'percent', NULL, 4, 20)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_8', N'% Efectividad, mes anterior', 18, N'percent', NULL, 4, 17)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'NUM_9', N'Clientes desembolsados', 23, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 22)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'DEN_9', N'Total clientes', 24, N'number', N'.0-0', 4, 23)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'DIV_9', N'% Efectividad', 25, N'percent', NULL, 4, 24)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_9', N'% Efectividad, mes anterior', 22, N'percent', NULL, 4, 21)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_10', N'CLIENTES NUEVOS', NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 7)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_11', N'PROSPECTOS', NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_18', N'EFECTIVIDAD CANCELADOS PRIORIDAD 2', NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 25)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_19', N'EFECTIVIDAD AMPLIACIÓN PRIORIDAD 2', NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 29)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_500', N'CARTERA TRAMO -30-0 D', NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 33)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_60', N'CARTERA TRAMO 1-30 D', NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 37)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_7', N'EFECTIVIDAD CRÉDITOS AUTOMÁTICOS', NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 13)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_8', N'EFECTIVIDAD CANCELADOS', NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 17)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_9', N'EFECTIVIDAD AMPLIACIÓN', NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 21)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_10', N'2 clientes nuevos x asesor', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 7)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_11', N'15 prospectos x asesor', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_18', N'8%', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 25)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_19', N'8%', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 29)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_500', N'95%', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 33)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_60', N'55%', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 37)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_7', N'12%', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 13)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_8', N'12%', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 17)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_9', N'12%', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 21)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_10', N'17-12-2019', NULL, NULL, NULL, 3, 7)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_11', N'17-12-2019', NULL, NULL, NULL, 3, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_18', N'17-12-2019', NULL, NULL, NULL, 3, 25)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_19', N'17-12-2019', NULL, NULL, NULL, 3, 29)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_500', N'17-12-2019', NULL, NULL, NULL, 3, 33)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_60', N'17-12-2019', NULL, NULL, NULL, 3, 37)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_7', N'17-12-2019', NULL, NULL, NULL, 3, 13)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_8', N'17-12-2019', NULL, NULL, NULL, 3, 17)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'AN_9', N'17-12-2019', NULL, NULL, NULL, 3, 21)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'EXT_10', N'20-01-2020', NULL, NULL, NULL, 3, 8)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'EXT_11', N'20-01-2020', NULL, NULL, NULL, 3, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'NUM_18', N'20-01-2020', NULL, NULL, NULL, 3, 26)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'NUM_19', N'20-01-2020', NULL, NULL, NULL, 3, 30)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'NUM_500', N'20-01-2020', NULL, NULL, NULL, 3, 34)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'NUM_60', N'20-01-2020', NULL, NULL, NULL, 3, 38)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'NUM_7', N'20-01-2020', NULL, NULL, NULL, 3, 14)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'NUM_8', N'20-01-2020', NULL, NULL, NULL, 3, 18)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'NUM_9', N'20-01-2020', NULL, NULL, NULL, 3, 22)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'descripcion', N'Descripción', 1, NULL, NULL, 2, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[tablajson] ([level], [columnDef], [header], [isdata], [type], [mode], [orden], [orden2]) VALUES (1, N'hitos', N'Hitos de la semana 3', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 1)




 select  distinct pr.orden as level,
            (
                select  tb.columnDef as [columnDef],
                        tb.header as [header],
                        tb.isdata as [isdata],
                        tb.type as [format.type],
                        tb.mode as [format.mode]
                        from #Tabla2 tb
                        where tb.orden = pr.orden
                        FOR JSON path

            ) as columns
            FROM #Tabla2 pr 
            order by orden asc
            FOR JSON path
```

Sale el siguiente resultado.

```
  [
    {
        "level": 1,
        "columns": [
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_10",
                "header": "2 clientes nuevos x asesor"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_11",
                "header": "15 prospectos x asesor"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_18",
                "header": "8%"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_19",
                "header": "8%"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_500",
                "header": "95%"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_60",
                "header": "55%"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_7",
                "header": "12%"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_8",
                "header": "12%"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_9",
                "header": "12%"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "hitos",
                "header": "Hitos de la semana 3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "level": 2,
        "columns": [
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_10",
                "header": "CLIENTES NUEVOS"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_11",
                "header": "PROSPECTOS"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_18",
                "header": "EFECTIVIDAD CANCELADOS PRIORIDAD 2"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_19",
                "header": "EFECTIVIDAD AMPLIACIÓN PRIORIDAD 2"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_500",
                "header": "CARTERA TRAMO -30-0 D"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_60",
                "header": "CARTERA TRAMO 1-30 D"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_7",
                "header": "EFECTIVIDAD CRÉDITOS AUTOMÁTICOS"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_8",
                "header": "EFECTIVIDAD CANCELADOS"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_9",
                "header": "EFECTIVIDAD AMPLIACIÓN"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "descripcion",
                "header": "Descripción",
                "isdata": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "level": 3,
        "columns": [
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_10",
                "header": "17-12-2019"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_11",
                "header": "17-12-2019"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_18",
                "header": "17-12-2019"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_19",
                "header": "17-12-2019"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_500",
                "header": "17-12-2019"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_60",
                "header": "17-12-2019"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_7",
                "header": "17-12-2019"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_8",
                "header": "17-12-2019"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "AN_9",
                "header": "17-12-2019"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "EXT_10",
                "header": "20-01-2020"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "EXT_11",
                "header": "20-01-2020"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "NUM_18",
                "header": "20-01-2020"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "NUM_19",
                "header": "20-01-2020"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "NUM_500",
                "header": "20-01-2020"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "NUM_60",
                "header": "20-01-2020"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "NUM_7",
                "header": "20-01-2020"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "NUM_8",
                "header": "20-01-2020"
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "NUM_9",
                "header": "20-01-2020"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "level": 4,
        "columns": [
            {
                "columnDef": "NUM_10",
                "header": "Total semanal clientes nuevos",
                "isdata": 11,
                "format": {
                    "type": "number",
                    "mode": ".0-0"
                }
            },
            {
                "columnDef": "DEN_10","
```

yo quisiera que el resultado sea así.

```
 [
    {
        "level":1,
        "columns":[
         {
          "columnDef":"DESCRIP",
          "header":"Descripción",
          "isdata":1,
          "sticky":true,
          "format":{
            "type":"string"
          },
          "rows":2
         },
         {
          "columnDef":"SSALMN",
          "header":"Saldo Puntual Captaciones",
          "isdata":2,
          "format":{
              "type":"number",
              "mode":".0-0"
            },
            "rows":2
         }
        ]
    },
    {
        "level": 2,
        "columns":[
            {
             "columnDef":"DESCRIP",
             "header":"Descripción",
             "isdata":1,
             "sticky":true,
             "format":{
               "type":"string"
             },
             "rows":2
            },
            {
             "columnDef":"SSALMN",
             "header":"Saldo Puntual Captaciones",
             "isdata":2,
             "format":{
                 "type":"number",
                 "mode":".0-0"
               },
               "rows":2
            }
           ]
    }
]
```

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres hacer eso? Si ocurre que entre los datos hay alguna comilla u otro carácter raro, podrías obtener un JSON inválido. SQL Server presenta el JSON así para evitar situaciones como esas. Revisa [este enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/how-for-json-escapes-special-characters-and-control-characters-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#escaping-of-special-characters). No veo qué problema tienes en manejar los datos así, se supone que lo que necesitas es un JSON válido y es lo que SQL Server te está devolviendo, para usarlo de algún modo ¿no?

Comment: el for Json ponlo afuera, al final de todo

Comment: @cedano hermano es que mira si yo hago solo de 1 sin el union all si sale sin las comillas, ademas en el back hay como una plantilla que tiene que estar del mismo esquema, he estado investigando en todo como poder quitar ya que solo aparece cuando hago el union all

Comment: @fredyfx si lo quito en las su consultas me Muestra un error

Comment: No sé, yo he leído que SQL Server hace eso de forma predeterminada cuando entre los resultados hay datos con comillas. ¿Si intentas el `UNION ALL` con una sola columna en el `SELECT`, preferiblemente numérica, sólo a modo de prueba, también lo hace?

Comment: @cedano igual le coloca ' y  \ ahora he intentado

Comment: @fredyfx lo probe y salio : La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza como expresión.

Comment: @fredyfx ahí he colocado lo que me indicaste la respuesta pero no es el mismo formato que deseo hermano

Comment: respuesta relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/320358/822

Comment: @fredyfx lo mio solo sale en sql server y no en .net por sql server también trate de hacer replace pero nada

Comment: Acabo de ver tu pregunta nuevamente, tienes casi casi lo que estás buscando. ¿Y si intentas agregar un TOP en donde creas conveniente?

Comment: @fredyfx si por eso hice un top 1 pero igual sale los símbolos ' \ , pero si lo hago sin el union all si sale sin los símbolos ' \

Comment: ¿Versión del sql server?

Comment: @fredyfx Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103581/discussion-between-pierodev-and-fredyfx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es, que el `UNION` elabora el resultado con la salida `json` ya convertida en texto, de ahí que el `FOR JSON auto` final este "escapeando" las comillas.

Entiendo que lo que buscas, podrías resolverlo así:

```
select  distinct pr.level,
        (
            select  tb.columnDef as [columnDef],
                    tb.header as [header],
                    tb.isdata as [isdata],
                    tb.type as [format.type],
                    tb.mode as [format.mode]
                    from tablajson tb
                    where tb.level = pr.level
                    FOR JSON auto

        ) as columns
        FROM tablajson pr 
        FOR JSON auto
```

Agrego una aclaración importante a partir de tus comentarios, la salida del `FOR JSON` varía de acuerdo del tamaño final, [aquí esta documentado](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#output-of-the-for-json-clause), que el resultado puede dividirse en múltiples filas. Hay varias alternativas para "juntar" el contenido final, [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/use-for-json-output-in-sql-server-and-in-client-apps-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#use-for-json-output-in-a-c-client-app) algunas posibilidades

Comment: ahora si me sale pero ahora no entiendo al momento de generar el json sale incompleto no genera bien el json

Comment: Hola @PieroDev, habría que ver con los datos , reales, en el ejemplo que has pasado, pareciera que lo hace bien, cualquier cosa estoy en el [chat].